# Reading CSV with multi-line columns in R

Tags: r, csv, fread

A dataset I am trying to read oddly contains a whole lot of multi-line texts in one column. `read.csv("the_ill_formated_file.csv")` is able to read some of it, with a number of columns mixed up for some rows then throws up a warning message

```
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string
```

`fread("the_ill_formated_file.csv")` is unable to read it at all throwing up this error message

```
Error in fread("the_ill_formated_file.csv") : 
  Internal error. No eol2 immediately before line 30, 'p' instead
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("the_ill_formated_file.csv") :
  Detected eol as \n\r, a highly unusual line ending. According to Wikipedia the Acorn BBC used this. If it is intended that the first column on the next row is a character column where the first character of the field value is \r (why?) then the first column should start with a quote (i.e. 'protected'). Proceeding with attempt to read the file.
```

The following is a snippet of how the file is formatted:

```
"comment_id", "comment", "post_date", "reply_count", "reply_ids"
1001, "This comment is multi-line with  

space between each line!

Quite a fancy format this one", "2015-08-16" , 3, "{1,2,3}"
1002, "This second row is all on a single line, which is the usual format read.csv/fread in R will expect it", "2015-08-17" , 0, "{}"
```

Got the same mixed up columns when I opened it in Excel. 
Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: have you checked if `allowEscapes=TRUE` within the `read.csv` call let you read the file?

Comment: `allowEscapes=TRUE` produces the same result (some rows are skipped, columns mixed up) only it does not throw the warning this time.

Comment: Hm, I just copied your two example lines and the header in a file and read it worked pretty fine. Where do you actually see the problem if you don't get an error message? Actually, for me it is working with and without `allowEscapes=TRUE`. The newlines get replaced with a `\n` in my case.

Comment: Interesting enough when I copy a sample out of it to test with, read.csv & fread work okay. Will just resort to python to reformat the data then load into R.