# R deletes rows from dataset without asking

Tags: r, linux, putty, delete-row, fault

To prepare my data for analysis I am filtering and merging six different datasets with use of R in PuTTY (Linux). Five of six datasets are properly read into R, but one isn't.
The dataset is (just like the other 5) a csv file named sire_ebv.csv and should have 56,141 rows which is what is confirmed when checking the number of rows in PuTTY. However, when simply reading the data into R, the dataset contains 42,875 rows. Somehow R deletes rows of the dataset. The following code is used to read the dataset into R:

```r
sireebv <- read.csv("sire_ebv.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

Head and tail were compared between PuTTY and R and were completely similar, also no double rows are present in the data.

Does anyone know what might cause this deletion of rows and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: the original file also does not contain empty lines.

Comment: If there are blank lines in the file, they will be ignored. Could be an explanation.

Comment: Thank you Aurele, however, there are no blank lines in the file as well. I added this info the post

Comment: It is difficult to help without seeing data. Maybe you could try to identify the missing rows in R and check in the csv file how they look like ? Maybe you could prepare and share a small csv file as an example with some of the rows that are missing in your R table, this would help to identify the issue faster

Comment: Check if the file has mixed line endings. Also maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048948/reading-csv-with-multi-line-columns-in-r

Comment: How are you counting the rows in the terminal?